# ArcPy add XY points and buffer

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, buffer

I've got some ArcPy code below which adds all the CSVs in a folder, adds them to the map (AddXYTableToPoint) and buffers the points.

I'm running in a Python notebook in ArcGIS Pro I only want to add the 'final' output, in this case the buffered points to the map.

Currently, the points are added along with the buffered points to the map.

```
path_list = []
    x_coords = "Latitude"
    y_coords = "Longitude"

for csv_file in csv_file_list:
    in_table = os.path.join(in_folder,csv_file)
    name = csv_file.strip(".csv")
    out_fc = name
    path_list.append(out_fc)
    arcpy.management.XYTableToPoint(in_table,out_fc,x_coords,y_coords)
    buffer_out = name + str('_buffer')
    arcpy.analysis.Buffer(out_fc,buffer_out,"500 Meters")
```

Comment: Are you running this code from the Python Window, a Python Script Tool or somewhere else?

Comment: You can either disable automatic addition of analysis products to the map canvas or remove the previous product after the fact.

Comment: @PolyGeo I'm running in a Python notebook in ArcGIS Pro
 I want to add the 'final' output, in this case the buffered points.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

To stop adding features automatically, set [arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/env.htm) to False. You then have to turn it back on to add the features. One way to code your solution is:

```
# Stop auto add outputs
arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = False

for csv_file in csv_file_list:
    in_table = os.path.join(in_folder,csv_file)
    name = csv_file.strip(".csv")
    out_fc = name
    path_list.append(out_fc)
    arcpy.management.XYTableToPoint(in_table,out_fc,x_coords,y_coords)
    buffer_out = name + str('_buffer')
    # turn on add outputs for duration of with
    with arcpy.EnvManager(addOutputsToMap = True):
        arcpy.analysis.Buffer(out_fc,buffer_out,"500 Meters")
```